# "Insert into table values" does not send data

Tags: python, sql-insert, mysql-python

I am new in this and this is my first question. I hope you guys will help. 
If my question format is wrong, feel free to comment on that also.

The code is pretty simple. I have DB connection, 2 functions - one for printing and another for choosing how many SQL queries I want to execute and input for those queries.

Idea is to enter a number(INT) of SQL queries - for example, 2 and then in another line user must enter 2 SQL queries. 
After that, call_table function will print out current table status/situation/data.

For example - user wants to print out into console table data (table have 2 columns, [name][college], varchar type)

```
Insert a number of SQL queries you want to execute: 1
Insert SQL statement: 
select * from student 
('ivan', 'ino')
('nena', 'fer')
('tomislav', 'ino')
('marko', 'fer')
('tomislav', 'ino')
('marko', 'fer')
```

When I try to insert some values into the same table nothing happens with the table, data is not entered.
The query is 100% correct since I tested it in workbench, also I've tried to create another table from this program and the query was executed normally and the table was created.

I receive no errors.

Code is below:

```
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='123456', database='test')

mycursor = db.cursor()

def call_table(data_print):
    for i in data_print:
        print(i)

def sql_inputs(cursor):
    container = []
    no = int(input("Insert a number of SQL queries you want to execute: "))
    for i in range(no):
        container = [input("Insert SQL statement: \n").upper()]
    for y in container:
        cursor.execute(y)

sql_inputs(mycursor)
call_table(mycursor)
```

What am I doing wrong? 
I tried even more complicated SQL queries but insert into the table is not working.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is good with the code, you're just missing `cursor.commit()`
By default cursor commit is false in python for insert queries.

```
cursor.execute(y)

cursor.commit()
```

and if you're done with queries

```
db.close()
```

Comment: I am receiving an error saying "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'commit'" or "AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'commit'... should I add a new variable with db.commit() or just new attribute into the function?

Comment: at the end of the code I've added 

sql_inputs(mycursor)
db.commit()
call_table(mycursor)

and now it's working as it should.

Maaaany thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should append the queries to the container variable

```
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='123456', database='test')

mycursor = db.cursor()

def call_table(data_print):
    for i in data_print:
        print(i)

def sql_inputs(cursor):
    container = []
    no = int(input("Insert a number of SQL queries you want to execute: "))
    for i in range(no):
        container.append(input("Insert SQL statement: \n").upper())
    for y in container:
        cursor.execute(y)

sql_inputs(mycursor)
call_table(mycursor)
```

Comment: thank you, I've changed it, but it didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the program, I've added db.commit(), and everything works fine now.

```
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='45fa6cb2', 
database='ivan')

mycursor = db.cursor()


def call_table(data_print):
    for i in data_print:
        print(i)

def sql_inputs(cursor):
    container = []
    no = int(input("Insert a number of SQL queries you want to execute: "))
    for i in range(no):
        container.append(input("Insert SQL statement: \n").upper())
    for y in container:
        cursor.execute(y)

sql_inputs(mycursor)
db.commit()
call_table(mycursor)
```